# How to group entries by multiple (i.e., all available) attributes with NaN values?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have to find out, which entries have the same valid features, namely if the data look so:

```
Idx    F1    F2    F3

1     NaN     A    23
2     0.2     B   NaN
3     NaN     C    12
4     NaN   NaN    88
5     0.7     D    41
6     0.1     E   NaN
```

the grouping should look so:

```
Group 1: [1, 3]
Group 2: [2, 6]
Group 3: [4]
Group 4: [5]
```

The problem is, that there are more than 2000 attributes, so I cannot list them manually in order to group by features explicitly.

Can somebody suggest me the way to do it using pandas?

Comment: Why is not `Group 1: [1, 3, 4]` ?

Comment: Because entries #1 and #3 have only NaN by feature F1, and the #4 has F1 and F2 as NaN

Comment: waht is output if `23` is `NaN` ? Why `Group 4: [5]` if no `NaN` in row?

Comment: check answer, I think it is what need

Comment: In case if `23` is `NaN` there will be 5 groups:
`Group 1: [1]
Group 2: [2, 6]
Group 3: [3]
Group 4: [4]
Group 5: [5]`

Comment: @jezrael inspired by you `.dot()` :)

Comment: @anky_91 - yes, good solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
(df.groupby((df.isna().dot(df.columns)).
     replace('','no_nan')).apply(lambda x: x.index.tolist()))
```

---

```
F1        [1, 3]
F1F2         [4]
F3        [2, 6]
no_nan       [5]
```

Comment: Thank you, it seems to work correctly. However, it takes extremely long time to compute (many hours in my case with 27000 entries and 2600 features) which is somehow very inefficient.